# Django form values not inserted in sqlite3 database tables

Tags: django, sqlite, django-forms, django-templates

I am a newbie in web development using Django.
I have created 3 models and correspondingly their forms. Even makemigrations and migrate commands did not report any problem and tables are also created in the SQLite DB file. 
But still, values are not getting inserted in the DB file. 
Empty QuerySet is getting received i.e. `<QuerySet []>`.
Could anyone please let me know why values do not get inserted? Thanks in advance.

**The program snippet:-**

**model.py**

```
class User(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='ABC')
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='ABC')

    def __str__(self):
        print("self.name:", self.name)
        return self.name

class Faculty_Info(models.Model):

    fid = models.IntegerField(default='123')
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="ABC")
    femail = models.EmailField(max_length=50, default='abc@gmail.com')
    fcontact = models.IntegerField(default='123')
    faddress = models.TextField(max_length=50, default='ABC')
    fsalary = models.IntegerField(default='123')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fname

class Student_Info(models.Model):

    sid = models.IntegerField(default='123')
    sname = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='ABC')
    semail = models.EmailField(max_length=50, default='abc@gmail.com')
    scontact = models.IntegerField(default='123')
    saddress = models.TextField(max_length=50, default='ABC')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sname
```

**views.py**

```
def faculty_info_section(request):
    faculties = Faculty_Info.objects.all()
    print("faculties", faculties)
    return render(request, "faculty_info_section.html", {'faculties': faculties})


def add_faculty(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        faculty_form = Faculty_Info_Form(request.POST)
        print("faculty_form", faculty_form)
        if faculty_form.is_valid():
            try:
                faculty_form.save()
                print("faculty_form:", faculty_form)
                return redirect('/faculty_info_section')
            except:
                pass
    else:
        faculty_form = Faculty_Info_Form()
    print("faculty_form_2", faculty_form)
    return render(request, 'add_faculty.html', {'faculty_form': faculty_form})
```

**faculty_info_section.html**

```
    {% for faculty in faculties %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ faculty.fid }}</td>
        <td>{{ faculty.fname }}</td>
        <td>{{ faculty.femail }}</td>
        <td>{{ faculty.fcontact }}</td>
        <td>{{ faculty.faddress }}</td>
        <td>{{ faculty.fsalary }}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="/edit/{{ faculty.id }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil">Edit</span></a>
            <a href="/delete/{{ faculty.id }}">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import Textarea

from School.models import User, Faculty_Info, Student_Info


class UserLoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = "__all__"


class Faculty_Info_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Faculty_Info
        widgets = {
            'fid': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 30, 'rows': 2}),
            'fname': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 30, 'rows': 2}),
            'femail': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 30, 'rows': 2}),
            'fcontact': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 30, 'rows': 2}),
            'faddress': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 30, 'rows': 2}),
            'fsalary': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 30, 'rows': 2}),
        }
        fields = "__all__"


class Student_Info_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student_Info
        widgets = {
            'sid': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 30, 'rows': 2}),
            'sname': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 30, 'rows': 2}),
            'semail': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 30, 'rows': 2}),
            'scontact': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 30, 'rows': 2}),
            'saddress': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 30, 'rows': 2}),
        }
        fields = "__all__"
```

Please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Gotta see your forms in order to say what may go wrong here. The rest of it looks fine, except I don't see why you need try/except block there and faculty_info_section.html seems irrelevant. Also I'd suggest going through the corresponding section in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/

Comment: Could anyone please answer my question ? ! @ Andrei Osmolovskii: Could you please look into it?

Comment: Everything looks standard. Print some more stuff out, e.g. `request.POST` to see what data your view function takes. Make sure that `form.save()` gets executed. To do that you may insert lines like: `print('request method is POST indeed')`, `print('form is valid')` in if/else blocks. Basically, you just need to be careful, because your example is pretty much equal to the one in the docs where they explain django forms.

Comment: In views.py, in add_faculty method, the request. method == Post is not entering into valid if code, rather it is entering inside else block without saving the form.

Comment: Is your `add_faculty.html` like this? `<form method="post">{% csrf_token %} {{ form }} <button type="submit">Submit</button></form>`

Comment: yes,  <form method="POST" class="post-form" action="/faculty_info_section"> . . . <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

Comment: add_faculty returns GET instead of POST even though the form has POST method..

Comment: @AndreiOsmolovskii: I have uploaded my repo on git, please review and let me know why database values are entering into database file. It would be of great help. The link is : https://github.com/JuhiGupta77/SchoolPortal

Comment: Remove this `action="/faculty_info_section"` from your form. In future if you want to specify action this way, use `{% url %} tag